# How to remove apostrophes from lists in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to calculate line averages from a `.csv` file and return a list of the averages of each line. Currently, I can get

```
in_ = [['1,2'], ['1,1,1,1'], ['-1,0,1'], ['42,17']]
```

but I need to remove the apostrophes as to average the individual lists! I have tried using `int()` but have had no luck.

My desired output

```
out = [[1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [-1, 0, 1], [42, 17]]
```

my current code is:

```
def line_averages(filename):
    """takes a file and returns the average values of each line in a
    .csv file"""
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    #print(lines)
    f.close()
    words = []
    for line in lines:
        words.append(line.split())
    for i in words:
        words.replace("'", "")
    return words
```

Comment: Thats because entire list element is one string. Try to split them first on `,` then cast to int

Comment: By *"remove apostrophes"* do you mean "convert strings to integers"? That might be easier to search for.

Comment: Could you show the code you're using to read from the csv file, please? There may be a way to do this automatically without a cumbersome post-processing step.

Comment: Your problem is not "how to remove apostrophes" but "how to read numbers from a CSV file"

Comment: Your question managed to avoid downvote hell and closure only *just*, because you added your own attempt at the solution. That gave me much more context to help you effectively. In future, make sure your question *starts* with that information.

Answer (score 4):

You are re-inventing the CSV-reader wheel here. Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to handle the splitting for you instead; we then only have to convert the string columns to integers:

```
def line_averages(filename):
    """takes a file and returns the average values of each line in a
    .csv file"""
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield [int(c) for c in row]
```

This produces a generator, and iteration gives you rows with integers:

```
for row in line_averages(some_file_name):
    # do something with each row
```

You can also return a list of lists:

```
def line_averages(filename):
    """takes a file and returns the average values of each line in a
    .csv file"""
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return [[int(c) for c in row] for row in reader]
```

Your attempt splits on *whitespace*, and not on commas. You'd have to explicitly split on `','`, and convert your columns to integers:

```
def line_averages(filename):
    """takes a file and returns the average values of each line in a
    .csv file"""
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return [[int(c) for c in line.split(',')] for line in f]
```

I used [nested list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) here to produce a list of lists, transforming each line from the file to a list of integers.

I also used the file as a [context manager in a `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with); this makes sure the file is closed no matter what happens in the managed block; there is no need to manually close it.

I also used the file as an *iterator*; each time you iterate (like the `for` loop would do) you get the next line in the file. There is no need to read all lines up front with `file.readlines()`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, when using this exact code it outputs:     <generator object line_averages at 0x181bb167d8>

Comment: @SebTerry: yes, you have an iterator. You can now use that in a `for` loop.